# Sending the contents of a matrix in one function to a matrix in another function

Tags: c, function, matrix

How can I pass the contents of a char matrix in one function to another matrix of equal dimensions in another function?

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the matrix contents the memcpy function.

```
/*
* mat: matrix to duplicate.
* rows: rows in mat.
* cols: cols in mat.
*/
void matdup(char mat[][],size_t rows,size_t cols){

    char dupmat[rows][cols];//duplicate matrix in stack.

    memcpy((void*)dupmat,(void*)mat,rows*cols);

    //do stuff with matrix here.
}
```

With this, you can have a new matrix to use inside of the matdup function.

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to know that the matrices are of constant size, the task is as simple as passing a double pointer (`char**` here) to the function, which refers to the matrix being passed.

You will need to pass the dimensions if the rows/columns of the passed matrix is unknown, however, since C does not track the size of arrays in memory (they are no more than pointers with syntactic sugar).

Comment: this assumes that his matrix is referred to as an array of pointers to arrays, while chances are he just has a regular contiguous 2-D array

Answer (score 1):

Pass the pointer to the first element in the matrix, and the size.